# Why aren't C++ libraries showing up for me while trying to set uop VSCode for C++ (MacOS)

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

hey im trying to set up vscode for c on my mac (MacOS Ventura 13.0, 1.4GHz intel core i5) following this [Using Clang in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) guide but when get to the step with the helloworld.ccp file, i get an error for my #includes saying "cannot open source file '[library]'", this is happening for all of the #includes in the given code and ive tried following instructions to install the libraries thru vcpkg but these libraries arent on there. ive followed all previous instructions like installing Xcode

ive tried restarting vscode a number of times, insstalling these libraries from different websites, looking for extensions that might help and for other ways of setting up vscode that dont require this method. im pretty new to coding so its probably something small messing it up but i havent been able to figure it out.

Comment: I dont use Mac but perhaps this is an issue with your PATH. Did you try to reboot your computer after installing the libraries and packages?

Comment: You don't include libraries but headers. What do you include that is not found?

Comment: I like how you're going out of your way to be vague. Your clock-speed is irrelevant, and it looks to be wrong as well. I had a 1.4 GHz Athlon in 2001. Did you actually follow the instructions? The command `clang --version` provides output in your terminal? Did you save your file? What are the exact errors you're getting?